# How to handle drag events on iphone and ipad with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I have a little app that has been under development for some time. My friends and I have been working really hard on this and are near release of the beta version.

I want to give some demos using iPhone and iPad to look cool :p

Now my problem is how to handle:

- Mouse Down
- Mouse Up
- Mouse Leave

The multitouch interface of the iPhone (which I expect is similar to the iPad) handles mouse move on a browser has a scrolling event. One could try to capture the scrolling event and use it to simulate the dragging but I don't even know if it will be doable or if it will only be a hack.

Any one knows of a more robust manner to manage dragging events on the iphone/ipad?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apple's Developer pages have a lot of good info on handling just these types of issues.

[Handling Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I realized that in the short time-span I had, developing codes to handle raw mouse (down, move and up) events would take time. So, I went ahead and modified the ThreeDumsMedia jQuery.event.drag plugin to make it to work on iPhone.

Get the jQuery.event.drag from http://www.shamasis.net/2011/06/javascript-drag-events-on-iphone-and-other-touch-based-devices/ and the 'drag' event would work just fine on iOS devices.

let me know if this helped.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery, then use [jquery.ui.mouse.touch.js](https://github.com/jhlagado/Mouse.Touch) with [jquery UI 1.9](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/09/jquery-ui-1-9-milestone-6-spinner-2/).

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

jquery.event.drag - v 2.2
Three Dub Media - http://threedubmedia.com